# Excel How to grab value in cell between two slashes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem of writing a right formula for this cell extraction.

My cell looks like this :

```
RED123/GREEN BLUE/543287-R231D321D/12345678910/0987654321.
```

I need to extract `543287-R231D321D` this value from a cell.

Tried to get some samples from other topics but didn't worked.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: If you have FILTERXML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml

Comment: IF not: `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),999*2,999))`

Comment: You can use the commands in excel "Left" and "Right"

An example to get the left part of the cell:

=LEFT(A1,FIND("-", A1)-1)

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner ! Problem was solved with formula =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),999*2,999))

Answer (score 0):

The `=TRIM` answer was creative, but a little too magical for my taste. Here's a pretty straight forward way to solve the problem:

```
=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A1, "/", 3), "/", 2)
```

It'll give you the text before the 3rd slash and after the 2nd slash. Easy to adjust if you want to extract another part.